# Getting keystrokes from the soft keyboard from within a fragment

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, keystroke, inputmethodmanager

I have an activity that launches a fragment whose main purpose is to present the user with an Imagebutton that they can click to launch the soft keyboard and type in whatever text they like. I need to grab each key as it is pressed on the soft keyboard. However, the user is not typing into an EditText view so I am struggling a bit with this. I can successfully display the soft keyboard when the user clicks the ImageButton using the code below...

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

However, I have not been able to find an example or a method that would let me grab the keystrokes from the soft keyboard without an EditText. I assume this must be possible I just don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps if you implement your own InputMethodService? You can overwrite the onUpdateSelection() method, which is called every time when a key is touched on the softkeyboard.